# JQUERY UI Autocomplete with 2 param

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I know that jquery ui use 'term' for filter data.
my problem is : how if i want to use multi field for filter data?
city as param1, and name as param2.
here is my autocomplete.

```
city='Jakarta';
$('#txt_name').autocomplete({
  source:path+'get_person.php?country='+city,
  select:function(event, ui){
    alert(ui.item.name);
  }
});
```

thank's before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first parameter will be used as the filter and passed along as `'term'`.  You can additionally pass other parameters via the URL, assuming they are accessible dynamically like so:

```
$('#txt_name').autocomplete({
  source:path+'get_person.php?city='+$("#city").val()+"&name="+$("#name").val(),
  select:function(event, ui){
    alert(ui.item.name);
  }
});
```

Where your form contains two input elements ID'd as `'name'` and `'city'`.

Then, in your script that performs the query, you'd have access to the filter with `$_GET['term']`, and access to your city and name variables with `$_GET['city']` and `$_GET['name']`, respectively.

Of course, it looks like you will be searching for a person  and filtering by their name?  In that case, you don't even have to pass along `&name=...` as `term` will contain the filter data you are looking for.

Comment: thank you so much. that great... so, 'term' can be replace with name.